# $ \max \{ \underset{x \in X}{\sup } f(x)\ , \underset{x \in X}{\sup } g(x) \} = \underset{x \in X}{\sup } \{ \max \{ f(x), g(x) \} \}$?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing, supremum-and-infimum

Let $f,g:  X \rightarrow [0, \infty )$ be bounded functions.

Does hold that

$$ \max \{  \underset{x \in  X}{\sup } f(x)\ , 
\underset{x \in  X}{\sup } g(x)  \}
= \underset{x \in  X}{\sup } \{  \max \{ f(x), g(x) \} \}$$

?

**My attempt**

Let $x \in X$. Then:

$$\max \{ f(x) , g(x) \} \leq \max \{  \underset{x \in  X}{\sup } f(x)\ , 
\underset{x \in  X}{\sup } g(x)  \} $$

Taking the sup, we have:

$$\underset{x \in  X}{\sup } \{  \max \{ f(x), g(x) \} \}
\leq  \max \{  \underset{x \in  X}{\sup } f(x)\ , 
\underset{x \in  X}{\sup } g(x)  \} $$

If $\max \{  \underset{x \in  X}{\sup } f(x)\ , 
\underset{x \in  X}{\sup } g(x)  \}  = \underset{x \in  X}{\sup f(x) }$ 
$\bigg(\underset{x \in  X}{\sup g(x) }\bigg)$, we have:

$$\max \{  \underset{x \in  X}{\sup } f(x)\ , 
\underset{x \in  X}{\sup } g(x)  \} 
\leq \underset{x \in  X}{\sup } \{  \max \{ f(x), g(x) \} \} $$

since  $f(x) \leq \max \{ f(x), g(x) \} \}$ 
$\bigg(g(x) \leq \max \{ f(x), g(x) \} \} \bigg)$, 
$\forall x \in X$

Am I right?

Comment: It looks right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second part looks good, though I'd proceed slightly differently. We don't need to worry about which supremum (if either) is the greater. Instead, we note that for any $x_0\in X$ we have $$f(x_0)\leq\max\bigl\{f(x_0),g(x_0)\bigr\}\leq\sup_{x\in X}\left(\max\bigl\{f(x),g(x)\bigr\}\right).$$ Hence, we have $$\sup_{x\in X}f(x)\le\sup_{x\in X}\left(\max\bigl\{f(x),g(x)\bigr\}\right).$$ Similarly, $$\sup_{x\in X}g(x)\le\sup_{x\in X}\left(\max\bigl\{f(x),g(x)\bigr\}\right),$$ and so $$\max\left\{\sup_{x\in X}f(x),\sup_{x\in X}g(x)\right\}\le\sup_{x\in X}\left(\max\bigl\{f(x),g(x)\bigr\}\right).$$

The first part needs more justification, to my mind. You can proceed in a similar way to the second part to get a nice proof with less "hand-waving."